# rxAndroidBle scan does not show any devices

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I downloaded the 1.5.0-rxjava2 release from [github](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/releases). Added the following in the manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

build and ran the app on my phone, gave it location permission, but when I START SCAN for bluetooth devices, it doesn't show anything, shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUO8I.jpg).

There are ble devices around, I try to use my ble app from google, it shows different devices.

What do I need to do in the sample rxAndroidBle app to make ble devices to show up?

**Update logcat output:**

```
    <com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample> is running.
05-24 11:12:17.908 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    CanvasContext() 0x7fad75f000
05-24 11:12:17.915 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7fa48cf7a0), client(30), share_fd(28)
05-24 11:12:17.915 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7fa48cf7a0) (w:1856 h:2048 s:1856 f:0x1 u:0x000100)
05-24 11:12:17.916 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/ViewRootImpl: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{19ab331 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity,ident = 0}
05-24 11:12:17.919 895-3919/? D/WindowManager: addWindowToListInOrderLocked: win=Window{4d02e0c u0 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.addWindow:2732 com.android.server.wm.Session.addToDisplay:171 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:124 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:133 
05-24 11:12:17.920 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{b0bc6cf token=android.os.BinderProxy@db0e85c {com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}} with isForward=true
05-24 11:12:17.920 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{19ab331 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5386206 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
05-24 11:12:17.920 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{b0bc6cf token=android.os.BinderProxy@db0e85c {com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}}
05-24 11:12:17.921 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{b0bc6cf token=android.os.BinderProxy@db0e85c {com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}}
05-24 11:12:17.955 276-276/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-276-29](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:0,p:-1,c:276) connect(C): consumer=(276:/system/bin/surfaceflinger) controlledByApp=false
    [unnamed-276-29](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:0,p:-1,c:276) setConsumerName: unnamed-276-29
    [com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:0,p:-1,c:276) setConsumerName: com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity
    [com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:0,p:-1,c:276) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1 height=1
05-24 11:12:17.956 895-1842/? V/WindowManager: Looking for focus: 6 = Window{32201d3 u0 StatusBar}, flags=-2122055608, canReceive=false
    findFocusedWindow: Found new focus @ 2 = Window{4d02e0c u0 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}
05-24 11:12:17.957 895-1842/? V/WindowManager: Changing focus from null to Window{4d02e0c u0 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity} Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:3528 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:201 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:284 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:133 
05-24 11:12:17.957 895-1842/? D/WindowManager: Input focus has changed to Window{4d02e0c u0 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}
05-24 11:12:17.960 276-276/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:0,p:-1,c:276) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1080 height=1920
05-24 11:12:17.963 895-957/? I/WindowManager: Focus moving from null to Window{4d02e0c u0 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}
    Gaining focus: Window{4d02e0c u0 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}
05-24 11:12:17.963 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7fad75f000 initialize window=0x7faf060c10, title=com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity
05-24 11:12:17.963 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7faf060c00)
05-24 11:12:17.967 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-24 11:12:17.969 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: Created EGL context (0x7fa4932780)
05-24 11:12:17.971 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/OpenGLRenderer: Get enable program binary service property (1)
    Initializing program atlas...
05-24 11:12:17.972 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getFileDescriptor
05-24 11:12:17.972 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapLen
    BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapArray
    BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramBinaryLen
05-24 11:12:17.972 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 173520, program map length is 152.
05-24 11:12:17.973 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 36, and path is /dev/ashmem�.
    No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(36).
05-24 11:12:17.973 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program cache from 0x7fb2c53bc8, size = 4
05-24 11:12:17.975 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000000000000)
05-24 11:12:17.976 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000800000003)
05-24 11:12:17.978 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000001000500040)
05-24 11:12:17.979 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000003800000000)
05-24 11:12:17.982 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7faf060c00,api=1)
05-24 11:12:17.982 276-363/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:1,p:5682,c:276) connect(P): api=1 producer=(5682:com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample) producerControlledByApp=true
05-24 11:12:17.982 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
05-24 11:12:17.983 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
05-24 11:12:17.999 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 2 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 306, 399
05-24 11:12:18.000 276-2068/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:1,p:5682,c:276) new GraphicBuffer needed
05-24 11:12:18.005 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7fa48d01a0), client(30), share_fd(38)
05-24 11:12:18.005 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7fa48d01a0) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
05-24 11:12:18.007 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache save to disk, size = 4
05-24 11:12:18.011 276-965/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:1,p:5682,c:276) new GraphicBuffer needed
05-24 11:12:18.017 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7fa48d04c0), client(30), share_fd(41)
05-24 11:12:18.018 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7fa48d04c0) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
05-24 11:12:18.023 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{74b02bb VFED.V... .F....ID 48,249-1032,1488 #7f080084 app:id/scan_results} softInputMode=272 first=true flags=#81810100
05-24 11:12:18.024 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{74b02bb VFED.V... .F....ID 48,249-1032,1488 #7f080084 app:id/scan_results} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4a54125 controlFlags=#105
05-24 11:12:18.025 895-957/? I/ActivityManager: [AppLaunch] Displayed Displayed com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity: +448ms
05-24 11:12:18.026 895-957/? D/ActivityManager: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_LaunchTime:com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity:448:567855
05-24 11:12:18.026 895-957/? V/WindowManager: Looking for focus: 6 = Window{32201d3 u0 StatusBar}, flags=-2122055608, canReceive=false
    findFocusedWindow: Found new focus @ 2 = Window{4d02e0c u0 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}
05-24 11:12:18.034 276-363/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:1,p:5682,c:276) new GraphicBuffer needed
05-24 11:12:18.042 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7fa48d0560), client(30), share_fd(44)
05-24 11:12:18.042 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7fa48d0560) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
05-24 11:12:18.046 5682-5691/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 1310
05-24 11:12:18.129 895-957/? D/ActivityManager: ACT-IDLE_NOW_MSG from windowsVisible() for idle: ActivityRecord{14ce5ba u0 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity t163}
05-24 11:12:18.130 895-957/? V/WindowManager: Looking for focus: 6 = Window{32201d3 u0 StatusBar}, flags=-2122055608, canReceive=false
    findFocusedWindow: Found new focus @ 2 = Window{4d02e0c u0 com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}
05-24 11:12:18.572 2317-2319/? D/GasService: FG app changed: from com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox to com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample
05-24 11:12:18.593 1086-1086/? D/SystemServicesProxy: getRecentTasks:TASK = Task.Key: 163, s: 5, u: 0, lat: 1527185537737, ComponentInfo{com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}/isExcluded = false/isTopTaskHome = true/isFirstValidTask = true/t.id = 163
    getRecentTasks:TASK = Task.Key: 156, s: -1, u: 0, lat: 1527147196021, ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity}/isExcluded = false/isTopTaskHome = true/isFirstValidTask = false/t.id = -1
05-24 11:12:18.601 1086-1086/? D/RecentsTaskLoadPlan:   thumbnail: Task.Key: 163, s: 5, u: 0, lat: 1527185537737, ComponentInfo{com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity}, null
05-24 11:12:19.208 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/ActivityThread: holder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@bd432fa, holder.provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@83e10ab
05-24 11:12:19.210 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/View: Touch down dispatch to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ........ 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569026, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
05-24 11:12:19.210 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: (View)dispatchTouchEvent: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569026, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ........ 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.210 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: (View)onTouchEvent 1: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569026, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },mTouchDelegate = null,enable = true,clickable = true,isLongClickable = false,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ........ 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    (View)Touch down: isInScrollingContainer = false,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ........ 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.212 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: handle Touch event by onTouchEvent, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569026, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }, this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P..ID 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.220 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = threefingers_takescreenshot , value = null
     from settings cache , name = threefingers_recent , value = null
05-24 11:12:19.221 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: (View)dispatchTouchEvent: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=569043, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P..ID 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    (View)onTouchEvent 1: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=569043, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },mTouchDelegate = null,enable = true,clickable = true,isLongClickable = false,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P..ID 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    (View)Touch move: x = 135.82979,y = 66.78552,mTouchSlop = 24,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P..ID 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    handle Touch event by onTouchEvent, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=569043, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }, this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P..ID 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.229 276-367/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:1,p:5682,c:276) queueBuffer: fps=1.64 dur=1218.03 max=1195.22 min=22.81
05-24 11:12:19.229 276-363/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample/com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity](this:0x7f8acec800,id:29,api:1,p:5682,c:276) new GraphicBuffer needed
05-24 11:12:19.236 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7fa48d06a0), client(30), share_fd(46)
05-24 11:12:19.237 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7fa48d06a0) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
05-24 11:12:19.239 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = threefingers_takescreenshot , value = null
     from settings cache , name = threefingers_recent , value = null
05-24 11:12:19.239 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: (View)dispatchTouchEvent: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=569062, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.240 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: (View)onTouchEvent 1: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=569062, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },mTouchDelegate = null,enable = true,clickable = true,isLongClickable = false,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    (View)Touch move: x = 135.82979,y = 66.78552,mTouchSlop = 24,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    handle Touch event by onTouchEvent, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=569062, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }, this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.250 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = threefingers_takescreenshot , value = null
     from settings cache , name = threefingers_recent , value = null
05-24 11:12:19.250 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: (View)dispatchTouchEvent: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569065, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    (View)onTouchEvent 1: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569065, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },mTouchDelegate = null,enable = true,clickable = true,isLongClickable = false,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    (View)Touch move: x = 135.82979,y = 66.78552,mTouchSlop = 24,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.251 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: handle Touch event by onTouchEvent, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569065, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }, this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.252 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = threefingers_takescreenshot , value = null
     from settings cache , name = threefingers_recent , value = null
05-24 11:12:19.252 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/View: Touch up dispatch to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569076, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
05-24 11:12:19.252 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: (View)dispatchTouchEvent: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569076, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.253 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: (View)onTouchEvent 1: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569076, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 },mTouchDelegate = null,enable = true,clickable = true,isLongClickable = false,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    (View)Touch up: prepressed = false,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    (View)Touch up: post perfomrClick runnable, this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
    handle Touch event by onTouchEvent, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=135.82979, y[0]=66.78552, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=569076, downTime=569026, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }, this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.255 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/View: (View)performClick, listener = com.polidea.rxandroidble2.sample.example1_scanning.ScanActivity_ViewBinding$1@d8dcaa1,this = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{82d57c1 VFED..C.. ...P.... 48,105-366,249 #7f080085 app:id/scan_toggle_btn}
05-24 11:12:19.267 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled
05-24 11:12:19.278 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = location_providers_allowed , value = network,gps
05-24 11:12:19.290 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/RxBle#ClientOperationQueue: QUEUED   ScanOperationApi21(44205254)
05-24 11:12:19.291 5682-5698/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/RxBle#ClientOperationQueue: STARTED  ScanOperationApi21(44205254)
05-24 11:12:19.297 5682-5721/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/RxBle#QueueOperation: Scan operation is requested to start.
05-24 11:12:19.300 5682-5721/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
05-24 11:12:19.302 5682-5721/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
    STATE_ON
05-24 11:12:19.302 5682-5699/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 2 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 179, 53, 84
05-24 11:12:19.304 5682-5721/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/BluetoothAdapter: getLeState() returning 12
05-24 11:12:19.311 5682-5719/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
05-24 11:12:19.317 895-1637/? D/AppOps: noteOperation: allowing code 0 uid 10104 package com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample
05-24 11:12:19.319 5682-5721/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.operations.ScanOperationApi21$1@21b6fdd=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@cad2f5f}
05-24 11:12:19.323 5682-5698/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/RxBle#ClientOperationQueue: FINISHED ScanOperationApi21(44205254) in 28 ms
05-24 11:12:20.805 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = threefingers_takescreenshot , value = null
     from settings cache , name = threefingers_recent , value = null
05-24 11:12:20.806 5682-5682/com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample I/View: Touch down dispatch to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{e8f2089 V.ED..... ........ 48,43-830,124}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=133.83163, y[0]=15.931808, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=570627, downTime=570627, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
```

**galaxy note 5 logs:**

```
I/RxBle#QueueOperation: Scan operation is requested to start.
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/addScanResult: reach  .subscribe resultsAdapter
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
                    STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7 mClientIf=0
D/RxBle#ClientOperationQueue: FINISHED ScanOperationApi21(56160292) in 121 ms
```

Comment: Can you specify what device you try to run your code on? Do you use the sample app or your own code? Could you show logs with `RxBleLog.setLogLevel(RxBleLog.VERBOSE)`?

Comment: I am running the sample app on UMI super phone. It's a fairly new phone. I just added the setLogLevel() code in the onCreate of the ScanActivity.java file. let me know if this is what you mean, I updated the logcat ouput.

Comment: Adding the log there is fine. I do not see any logs that are from the application `com.polidea.rxandroidble.sample` package, could you double-check if you have set it up properly?

Comment: I updated the logcat, let me know if that what you mean @DariuszSeweryn

Comment: I did some logcat print statements, it seems like it the resultsAdapter.java file is never getting called.

Comment: In the logs everything seems to be ok.

Comment: I downloaded this app on a galaxy note 5 as well, and it didn't show any scan results, do you have any suggestion on what I can do? Also, I added the logs from the galaxy note 5@DariuszSeweryn

Comment: Hmmm... And do you have `Location Services` turned on?

Comment: On the phone, yes @DariuszSeweryn